# Canyon CNE-CWC1 webcam, Microdia Camera, horrible picture quality

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, webcam, camera

got me a Canyon CNE-CWC1, it's a cheap camera but the quality overall is passable. But not on Ubuntu, the quality is horrendous. Not sure what else can I provide you with, I usually need it for Google Meets on Chrome.

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0c45:6340 Microdia Camera
```

That's about as far as my Linux knowledge goes, is there anything I can do about this? Tried running

```
lsusb -s 003:004 -v | grep -E "Width|Height" 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        wWidth                            352
        wHeight                           288
        wWidth                            320
        wHeight                           240
        wWidth                            176
        wHeight                           144
        wWidth                            160
        wHeight                           120
        wWidth( 0)                        640
        wHeight( 0)                       480
        wWidth( 1)                        352
        wHeight( 1)                       288
        wWidth( 2)                        320
        wHeight( 2)                       240
        wWidth( 3)                        176
        wHeight( 3)                       144
        wWidth( 4)                        160
        wHeight( 4)                       120
```

But doesn't seem like much info

Comment: That camera has [a spotty reputation](http://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0c45-6340) on Linux. Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @matigo oh, didn't even know about that website. 20.04 version